# Pandas- How can I eliminate trailing whitespace in the index

Tags: python, string, pandas, removing-whitespace

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'two three', 'f four   ', 'three '], 'B': [10,20,30,40]})

df = df.set_index('A')
```

Here is what the df needs to be:

```
            B
A   
one        10
two three  20
f four     30
three      40
```

In the final data frame, the spaces in indices should be removed if they are trailing. If they are anywhere else, they need to remain. So the trailing spaces in 'three ' and 'f four   ' need to be deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
print (df.index.tolist())
['one', 'two three', 'f four   ', 'three ']

df.index = df.index.str.strip()
print (df)
            B
A            
one        10
two three  20
f four     30
three      40

print (df.index.tolist())
['one', 'two three', 'f four', 'three']
```

Another solution is use `rename`:

```
df = df.rename(lambda x: x.strip())
```